# Rust: обобщённые вещественные значения

Tags: generics, float, rust

Пытаясь написать обобщённые функции для работы с вещественными аргументами столкнулся с необходимостью использовать константные значения.

Код на С++:

```
template <typename T>
T multiplyBy0_6 (T value) {
     return value * 0.6;
}

template <typename T>
T divideBy0_6 (T value) {
     return value / 0.6;
}
```

Не могу разобраться, как записать то же самое на Rust, точнее как получить обобщённые значения для 0.6. Что для этого следует использовать? FromPrimitive, From, Into, NumCast? Из документации ничего уяснить не удаётся.

Код на Rust:

```
extern crate num;

use num::Float;

fn multiply_by_0_6 <T: Float> (value: T) {
    value * ?(0.6)
}

fn divide_by_0_6 <T: Float> (value: T) {
    value / ?(0.6)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В модуле `num::cast` есть функция [`cast()`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/cast/fn.cast.html). Можно воспользоваться ею.

Для сокращения количества кода можно сделать вспомогательную функцию, которая будет решать что делать, если константу нельзя преобразовать к требуемому типу (например преобразование `1.0e256` к `f32`).

```
#[inline]
fn c<T: NumCast, U: NumCast>(v: T) -> U {
    num::cast(v).expect("cast error")
}
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть так

```
fn multiply_by_0_6 <T: Float> (value: T) -> T {
    value * c(0.6)
}

fn divide_by_0_6 <T: Float> (value: T) -> T {
    value / c(0.6)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=46a205731f4fd234aff5b7f204a63f6a&version=stable)

Comment: Спасибо! А результаты возвращаемые функцией `c` нельзя как-нибудь в константы оформлять?

Comment: Пока нет (нужны `const fn`, до стабилизации которых пока ещё далеко). Но оптимизатор выкинет всё лишнее и оставит константу.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающее объяснение!